# Appending # of items to row according to number in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, for-loop

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/km5IL.png), Process[/logical flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quWBO.png)

Here is a sample of the first dataset:
[list of symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83KxD.png)

Here is a sample of the second dataset that I am using as a reference to group first dataset symbols: [reference for grouping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZmLf.png)

And here is my code:

```
stockN = pd.DataFrame(numstocks)
ticker = pd.DataFrame(ticks)

sorts = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Symbols'])

for x in range(len(stockN)):
    if int(stockN[0][x]) < 10:
        sorts.loc[x] = str(ticker[0][:x])
    if int(stockN[0][x]) > 10:
        sorts.loc[x] = str(ticker[0][x:x+10])
```

And my output is:

```
0   Series([], Name: 0, dtype: object)
1   0 GRA\nName: 0, dtype: object
2   2 RL\n3 UNVR\n4 EPC\n5 OI\n6 LEA\nName: 0, dtype: object
3   0 GRA\n1 WRK\n2 RL\nName: 0, dtype: object
4   0 GRA\n1 WRK\n2 RL\n3 UNVR\nName: 0, dtype: object
```

So- clearly, passing a str() is creating some problems already, but if I don't, the values are filled with NaN.
So why am I accessing more than just the contents of what I indicated?

My next issue is the slicing, as you can tell the logic there is a disaster but since I can't access the stockN number, I can't add that to my x variable. I assumed that I could create my data frame row by row and fill each row with the ticker symbols from ticker[x:x+y] where y = stockN(quantity). That value would then be used for the next iteration and so forth.

Edit: Forgot to mention that the ticker symbols per row are a max of 10, so if my stockN number is 27 for example, I only want the next 10, not 27. That's why the if/else and the x+10 slice.

Please let me know if you can help me. If you have a better way of going about this that would be very much appreciated too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out! Hopefully this helps anyone else looking for a similar solution, even though this is a relatively basic question.

First of all- while my nStocks values from the previous post displayed as numbers they were actually strings. So I fixed that by accessing the data frame at [0] and converting the values to back to a list, and then turning them to int with a list comprehension.

```
sCount = stockN[0].values.tolist()
sCount = [int(i) for i in sCount]
```

After that everything was much easier, and instead of creating a messy/complex slicing method I just dropped the rows as I accessed them (duh).

```
symbol = []
for x in range(len(sCount)):
    if sCount[x] <= 10:
        symbol.append(ticker[0][:sCount[x]])
        ticker.drop(ticker.index[:sCount[x]], inplace=True)
        
    if sCount[x] > 10:
        symbol.append(ticker[0][:10])
        ticker.drop(ticker.index[:10], inplace=True)
```